# How to change theme colors?

Tags: themes, colors

I have searched the web and cannot find an easy way to change the brown/orange colors to something like greens.

Are there tools/tips to change the theme colors?

Answer (score 5):

A useful tool to customize gtk theme is gtk-theme-config.

You can see here the greybird gtk theme wich has a blue scheme by default turned to purple and the gtk theme config at the bottom right corner.

Greybird gtk them wich has a blue scheme by default.

[image]

For install it in Saucy 13.10 and Trusty 14.04:

```
sudo apt install gtk-theme-config
```

For previous ubuntu releases:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gtk-theme-config
```

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/customize-gtk3-gtk2-theme-colors-using.html

**Important**

Notice this will not work with the new default themes in ubuntu as explained here: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/ambiance-and-radiance-colors-theme-pack.html

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is more green, just install one of the themes available at [ubuntu-art.org](http://ubuntu-art.org/content/show.php?content=147891):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is maybe to install the color-varied versions of Radiance and Ambiance: [Ambiance & Radiance Colors](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/download-ambiance-radiance-colors.html).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-colors radiance-colors
```

And then change the theme with Unity Tweak Tool.

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

As for the icons, we can [change only the color](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/change-color-of-folder-ubuntu-16-04/) if we want, while keeping the same theme (in fact creating a color-variation version of the default) with:

```
sudo apt remove folder-color folder-color-caja folder-color-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color

sudo apt update

sudo apt install folder-color folder-color-caja
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were looking for 8 years ago, but right now (maybe this would help someone out there) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you can go to
*Settings*  -> *Appearance*, in the *Style* section go to *Color* and pick between different shades of green.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3sZP.png)